# Akka cluster with nodes deployed in different data centers

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, nodes, sharding

I have question about Akka cluster deployment best practices.

Is it recommended to have nodes each deployed in different data center (for example one in Europe and one in US, etc)?

The reason for that is to reduce network latency for cluster clients accessing the cluster. I think that, such a nodes should respond faster to nearby clients.

Thanks for responses.

Comment: There are settings in Akka Cluster that supports the idea of having cluster deployed across multiple data centers. Link to documentation:
[Cluster across multiple data centers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-dc.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that you have an Akka cluster deployed with members spread across different data centres. Instead you should deploy a separate Akka cluster in each of the data centres, and if you need to communicate between them you should use something like [Cluster Client](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-client.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this thread. I would like to add a couple of interesting seminars to answer the question:

- [How To Extend Akka Resilience And Scalability Across Datacenters](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/advanced-akka-for-architects-multi-datacenter-clustering-persistence)

And just a general seminar: [A Comprehensive Overview Of A To Z With Akka](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/akka-revealed-jvm-architects-journey-from-resilient-actors-to-scalable-clusters)